# Why was my question about migrating VB.NET developers closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I asked a [question about VB.NET and C#](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96845/why-are-vb-net-developers-are-migrating-to-c), but a moderator closed it within a few minutes of it being asked without allowing the community to decide whether it should be worthy of the site.

I want to know, how can I appeal this action? Why don't moderators wait until other members of the community weigh in before closing?

Comment: Related: [What are the rules around moderators closing questions outright?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-rules-around-moderators-closing-questions-outright)

Comment: @Mark: So there were a lot of votes to close it, or there are not yet enough people on the Programmers site with vote to close ability?

Comment: @Jim My apologies: an older question—from early beta when there weren't enough people able to close questions—was incorrectly marked as a [tag:faq] question so I used that. I've updated the link, which contains guidance from SE, Inc. about the issue. Generally, moderators are given freedom to use their judgement, and the software is designed specifically for that purpose.

Comment: I think I would almost like to see a vote to reopen so long as we can vote to to keep closed as well. This would help with this I think.Though I do think that more than a simple majority should be required to reopen.  I would hope at this point anyway that this question would stay closed.

Comment: @Chad The reopen is the exact reverse of the close action, and has the same rules: 5 votes from regular users, or 1 vote from a moderator. To that end, an especially controversial question can flip multiple times if a moderator doesn't lock the question first.

Comment: I do not see a reopen option on most closed questions.  Is that because they get locked?  Maybe there should be a change to the logic on the reopen so that it is harder to reopen a question to avoid this.

Comment: @Chad Closed questions aren't typically locked. Casting close and reopen votes is a privilege that unlocks at 3000 rep. Until then, you can flag posts for reopening instead.

Answer (score 2):

> how can OP sue such an action.

I suspect you already know this, but you can't sue because the moderator of a website did something you don't like. About the most you can do is bring it up on meta like you already have

> He at least could wait for other moderators to vote for close up.

Moderators can't vote, they just act. If you mean he could've waited for other *users* to vote, I suppose so, but moderators are elected because they understand how their respective sites work -- their judgement is generally pretty good

> Closing a question on a single thought is true dictatorship and egoistic

It's not a dictatorship; again, they were [elected](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1). And I know ChrisF well enough to be confident he doesn't get an ego boost closing questions, he's just trying to keep the quality of the site high. The [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) explains what questions are off-topic

Comment: It's ridiculous @Michael. They have closed [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96854/are-there-technical-advantages-for-c-over-vb-net) question, which is very similar to mine, as **duplicate**, not as **not constructive**. This proves that your theory of moderators making the correct decision is wrong. Also this question has got the chance to be answered before being close.

Comment: @Saeed It was closed as a duplicate of a question which itself was closed as not constructive, so I'm not sure what your point is

Comment: if you're talking about [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/vb-net-vs-c-debate) question, it's got 16 upvotes, 5 likes and 21 upvotes for the top answer. That's what I call community judgement. That's why I say that moderators are not fair. Community is mature enough to recognize this question as a valid one, with upvotes support.

Comment: @Saeed You're getting into a whole different argument about what questions should be allowed, which has been covered on meta.programmers for months and certainly won't fit in this comment thread. The only thing I'm saying is your question was closed for the same reason that question was closed